# StructureDefinition post request return 404 error

Tags: hapi-fhir

I have just done the local setup of hapi fhir in my machine.
And I can able to reach the fhir metadata `http://localhost:8888/fhir/metadata` but when I try to post any structure Definition using this url(`http://localhost:8888/StructureDefinition`) its returning "Error 404 Not Found".

This is the error from local setup:

```
2021-03-01 13:12:20.441 [qtp1256142210-23] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /StructureDefinition
2021-03-01 13:12:20.446 [qtp1256142210-23] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /error
2021-03-01 13:12:40.279 [qtp1256142210-19] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /StructureDefinition
2021-03-01 13:12:40.280 [qtp1256142210-19] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /error
2021-03-01 13:12:45.532 [qtp1256142210-23] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /StructureDefinition
2021-03-01 13:12:45.533 [qtp1256142210-23] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /error
2021-03-01 13:13:03.615 [qtp1256142210-19] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound [DispatcherServlet.java:1271] No mapping for POST /StructureDefinition
```

What is the issue? Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for my question below,

I should include `/fhir` like this `http://localhost:8888/fhir/StructureDefinition`.

And it is working now.